# CentOS: convert HTML `<br>` tags to bash `\n\r` on the fly?

Tags: centos, php, bash, html

this is a tough question to pose and i'm not entirely sure this is the right place for it, but my question is this:

how can i convert `<br>` tags to `\n\r` characters on the fly when running a PHP script from bash?

why?  because usually the script runs in a browser, thus the `<br>` but sometimes i need to run it from the console because: faster and SSH.  and the logging output, normally all nice in a browser, becomes a text wall on the console.  i'd like to run it and just have something where the `<br>` tags are replaced with `\n\r` on the fly so the original document doesn't change (it can't) but i still get nice output on the terminal.  `awk`?  `sed`?  not sure how best to proceed.

thinking something like:

```sh
php -f myFile.php | sed 's/<br>/\n\r'
```

and if this is the wrong spot for this question, please point me to the right one.  thank you.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/673878/144961

Comment: is SuperUser the better forum for this kind of question?

Comment: There are already good answers there, so probably yes.

Answer (score 1):

okay.  the `sed` option works.  i'd mistakenly confused my slashes, but they are correct and works perfectly.  i'll leave this up in case anyone else has a similar questions, but if admins want to turf it, so be it.

```
php -f myFile.php | sed 's/<br>/\n\r/gp'
```